# browser keeps on looking for the data but never fetches it

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, servlets

Following is a snippet that is meant to fetch the data from the database. But when i click the *submit button* to see the data, the browser keeps on looking for the data but never displays anything *(the browser doesn't show the next page but keeps on looking on the same page)* . I don't know what the problem is.

*Snippet that fetches the data :*

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException {
    try {
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDatasource");
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        String sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION";
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
        ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
         while(set.next()) {
            writer.println(set.getString(1) + " " + set.getString(2) + " " + set.getString(3));
            writer.println(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

    }catch(Exception exc) {

    }
```

*Html code:*

```
<form method="get" action="GetFromDatabase.do"> <br />
<input type="submit" value="List All Members" />
```

Comment: WHere is the datasource defined? Are you sure the xxx.do is being resolved? (I mean, if you comment out the whole query and do a system.out("hello"), does it print out in standar output? Check logs and bring more info

Comment: You are ignoring any exceptions thrown.  Don't do that.  If something is going wrong, then there might be an exception telling you exactly what is failing.

Comment: @ Alfabravo yes it does print hello if i comment out the query.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things for you to check,

1. Instead of suppressing your exception, at least print stacktrace out.

   catch(Exception exc) {

   ```
   exc.printStackTrace();
   ```

   }

If there is any exception we can find the real problem.

1. What kind of response you want to send ? I can see

   ```
   response.setContentType("text/plain");
   ```

Do you really want to send the response as a plain text, as oppose to text/html.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement:

```
writer.flush();
```

Comment: Completely unnecessary. The container already does that. Unless the webapp in question is using a custom `HttpServletResponseWrapper` which has a badly implemented `flushBuffer()` method or which returns in turn a custom `ServletOutputStream` and/or `PrintWriter` with a badly implemented `flush()` method.